# Why does the end=' ' argument in print() get printed twice when used in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, printing

There is a text file that I am reading from.

```
for line in file:
    print(line, end='1')
```

The keyword argument '1' gets printed twice - once at the end of each line as expected but another at the beginning of the next line.

[image: the output]

this is the output

Comment: It's only printed once per line, but your lines appear to end with newline characters.

Comment: When you loop over a file, each line ends in a newline (exception possibly the last).

Comment: Use `print(line.strip(), end="1")` to remove the newlines from the lines.

Comment: I don't agree with the explanation in the comments. Please show also the input text (preferably not as a picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Textfile probably contains empty lines between those sentences. Those empty lines will get printed as well with a "1" at the end.